# the function x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey return rsa.privateKey. But can't use in the encryptPKCS1v15 function

Tags: go, encryption, rsa

```
const strPrivateKey = "30820b82020100300d06092a864886f70d010101050004820b6c30820b680201000282028100acfc585f43ca36ec2dddc518b5c7d1303b658faec58b634aff16ce4b7930b93a23517f8d9c8a260f4e2eb44b01da5b6588fefe63acb68c15677"

decoded, err := hex.DecodeString(strPrivateKey)
if err != nil {
    return ""
}
privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(decoded)
if err != nil {
    return ""
}

encypt, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, &privateKey.PublicKey, data)
if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
    return ""
}
```

```
privateKey.PublicKey undefined (type any has no field or method PublicKey)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Your questions about code, i.e. debugging questions like these, are served by not only providing the code + error message, but also a textual description on what the code is supposed to do, and what it currently does, see [mcve]. Also showing what you have already tried to solve the problem is appreciated. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

According to the doc (https://pkg.go.dev/crypto/x509@go1.19.3#ParsePKCS8PrivateKey):

> func ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(der []byte) (key any, err error)
>
> ...
> It returns a `*rsa.PrivateKey`, a `*ecdsa.PrivateKey`, or a `ed25519.PrivateKey`. More types might be supported in the future.

You should use [type assertion](https://go.dev/ref/spec#Type_assertions) to check the type of the key:

```golang
switch privateKey := privateKey.(type) {
case *rsa.PrivateKey:
    // ...
case *ecdsa.PrivateKey:
    // ...
case ed25519.PrivateKey:
    // ...
default:
    panic("unknown key")
}
```

Since `rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15` expects a `*rsa.PublicKey`, your code can be written like this:

```golang
if privateKey, ok := privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey); ok {
    encypt, err := rsa.EncryptPKCS1v15(rand.Reader, &privateKey.PublicKey, data)
}
```

BTW, the provided `strPrivateKey` is invalid (`encoding/hex: odd length hex string`). You can get some valid private keys from https://github.com/golang/go/blob/1c05968c9a5d6432fc6f30196528f8f37287dd3d/src/crypto/x509/pkcs8_test.go#L52-L124

Comment: Thank you. I resolved privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)

Answer (score 0):

***correct answer. I resolved privateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)***

```
decodedString, err := hex.DecodeString(utility.StrPrivateKey)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
pkcs8PrivateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(decodedString)
if err != nil {
    return err
}
privateKey := pkcs8PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey)
```

Comment: You should always check if the value can be used as the other type, otherwise your code will panic: `privateKey, ok := pkcs8PrivateKey.(*rsa.PrivateKey); if !ok { /*return error */ }`